# Change the background on Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, background-image

I am trying to change background image on Windows Phone 8 project. And I am writing the following code in MainPage.xaml:

```
<phone:Panorama.Background>
   <ImageBrush ImageSource="/PanoramaApp1;component/Assets/arka.png"/>
</phone:Panorama.Background>
```

But not changing the when I run.

[image: Here is screenshot.]

What is my problem?
Thanks in advance.
(Sorry my language.)

Comment: if it is displayed in designer(i.e. path is correct) and not in emulator ,then you probably might not set Resource Build Action to Content mistakenly.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Layoutroot background to transparent. 
And

```
  <phone:Panorama.Background>
     <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/Tiles/arka.png"/>     
  </phone:Panorama.Background>
```